# How to change a live data instance in view model?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am setting a room query in onCreate() which returns a live data instance that I observe in the following.

```
viewModel.setmQueryMediaList(null, MediaUtils.DATE_TAKEN_KEY, MediaUtils.DATE_TAKEN_KEY);

viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<MediaStoreData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MediaStoreData> mediaStoreDataList) {
            List<MediaStoreData> sectionedMediaStoreDataList = MediaUtils.getSectionedList(getBaseContext(), mediaStoreDataList, MediaUtils.ORDER_BY_MONTH );
            mRecyclerViewAdapter.submitList(sectionedMediaStoreDataList);
            Log.e("MediaDatabase", "something changed! Size:" + (mediaStoreDataList != null ? mediaStoreDataList.size() : 0));
        }
    });
```

`onClick()` I want to change the room query and I assumed that the observer triggers on that change but it doesn't.

```
@Override
public void onAlbumClicked(AlbumData albumData, TextView titleView) {
    viewModel.setmQueryMediaList(albumData.getDirectory_path(), null, MediaUtils.DATE_TAKEN_KEY);
    mSlidingUpPanelLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.EXPANDED);
}
```

This is in my ViewModel class

```
public void setmQueryMediaList(String directory_path, String sectionOrder, String sortOrder) {
    if(directory_path != null){
        this.mQueryMediaList = mediaDatabase.mediaDao().getAllByName();
    } else {
        this.mQueryMediaList = mediaDatabase.mediaDao().getAllByDate();
    }
}

public LiveData<List<MediaStoreData>> getmQueryMediaList(){
    return mQueryMediaList;
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you replace the Object which has the Observer attached.
That means that you Obserers are not attached to your new QueryMediaList, so you would need to reset them every time you change the Query.
To do that you could extract your Observer into its own variable, and then reatach that variable to the list, after you changed the query.

Comment: `private void handleQueryMediaList(String directory_path, String sectionOrder, String sortOrder){
        if(viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().hasObservers()){
            viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().removeObservers(this);
        }
        viewModel.setmQueryMediaList(directory_path, sectionOrder, sortOrder);
        viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().observe(MainActivity.this, mObserver);
    }`   This is how I implemented it, but now the app isn't even launching and is showing no error log....@glm9637

Comment: shouldn't  `viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().removeObservers(this);` be: `viewModel.getmQueryMediaList().removeObservers(mObserver);` ? Since you want to remover your observer?

Comment: I tried both. I fixed it. Dumb mistake as I was calling .removeObersers(this) on a null reference... Extracting of the observer into its own variable is the key! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this would be to put the `directoryPath` in a `MutableLiveData<String>`, then do a `Transformations.switchMap` by it to update the LiveData that you're actually observing from your Activity/Fragment.

```
public void setmQueryMediaList(String directoryPath, String sectionOrder, String sortOrder) {
    directoryPathLiveData.setValue(directoryPath);
}

mQueryMediaList = Transformations.switchMap(directoryPathLiveData, (directoryPath) -> {
    if(directory_path != null){
        return mediaDatabase.mediaDao().getAllByName();
    } else {
        return mediaDatabase.mediaDao().getAllByDate();
    }
});
```